# ViewState not saving values during PostBack

Tags: vb.net, viewstate

I'm making a webapp with vb.net, and I need to make a TextBox inside an UpdatePanel to change focus to another textbox after a PostBack. I decided to use a ViewState to save a numbre that will be read on loading to know where the focus should be(there are seven textboxes supposed to work like that), but I can't make only one work.
Here is the minimum code that does not work.

```
     Dim g As Integer
    g = 1
    ViewState.Add("foco", g)
```

And here is the Page_Load.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        If ViewState("foco") = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Focus()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not incrementing the counter between postbacks.

```
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        If ViewState("foco") = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Focus()
        ElseIf ViewState("foco") = 2 Then
            TextBox2.Focus()
        ElseIf ViewState("foco") = 3 Then
            TextBox3.Focus()
        End If
        ViewState("foco") = ViewState("foco") + 1
    Else
        ViewState.Add("foco", 1)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

When is the code that adds a value to ViewState executed?

What do you mean by "does not work"?  What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

In any case, the simplest way to do this might be to add a property to your Page that is backed by ViewState, e.g.:

```
public int FocusIndex
{
    get 
    {
        object o = ViewState["foco"];
        return (o == null) ? -1 : (int) o;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["foco"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a TextBox on an UpdatePanel, when pressing enter, it's supposed to fill a List with results from a database and then save the number of textbox to focus when the postback returns. I posted the code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Protected Sub TextBox7_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox7.TextChanged
    If TextBox7.Text = "" Then Exit Sub


    '  ListBox1.Visible = True


    ListBox1.Items.Clear()



    Dim con As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=TEST08\AXSQLEXPRESS;Password=Axoft1988;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=club_independiente")
    con.Open()

    'Dim com As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from emCaja where cod_client = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", con)
    ' If "" & com.ExecuteScalar() = "" Then
    Dim com As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand

    com = New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from emConceptos where codigo = " & TextBox7.Text, con)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim dr As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    dr = com.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("descripcion"))
        ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1).Value = dr("codigo")
    End While
    dr.Close()

    ' ListBox1.Focus()

    If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
    Dim g As Integer
    g = 1
    Session("foco") = g

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing doesn't work because the page_load method runs before the TextChanged event has a chance to execute.

Try this:

1. add a scriptmanager in your page;
2. Put your page_load logic in the page_preRender event, which is guaranteed to fire afer the textchanged event;

   ```
   Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender

       If Page.IsPostBack Then
           If ViewState("foco") = 1 Then
               ScriptManager1.SetFocus(TextBox1)
           End If
       End If

   End Sub
   ```